# Use searchfield in mmenu for normal search

Tags: jquery, search, mmenu

I'm trying to implement the mmenu (http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) for my homepage.

In the advanced example there is a searchfield, that searches the menus content.
I wonder if the searchfield instead could be used as a normal search on the homepage rather than searching the menus content?

And I don't want it to search after each keystroke, but only when hitting the ENTER-key. Could this be done?

Comment: Then you can try to remove the event `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` and use `if(e.KeyCode == 13)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mmenu plugin offers the option to add the searchfield, without adding the search function.
That way you can and bind your own function to the "change" event:

```
$("#foo").mmenu({
    searchfield:{
        add: true,
        search: false
    }
});
$("#foo .mm-search input")
    .bind( "change", function() {
        // do your search

        // maybe close the menu?
        $("#foo").trigger( "close" );
    }
);
```

Answer (score 5):

That way you can create a normal search event:

```
$("#foo").mmenu({
    searchfield:{
        add: true,
        search: false
    }
});
$("#foo .mm-search input").keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        window.location.href = 'search.php?q=' + $(this).val();
    }
});
```